# Chrome opening for split second and throws exception using Selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome

```
        namespace Selenium_test
        {
        class Program
        {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        string Path = @"C:\Users\Anjali10\.nuget\packages\WebDriverChromeDriver\2.10.0\tools";
        //Create the reference of our browser
        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(Path);

        // Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3000));
        Thread.Sleep(300000);
        //Navigate to google page
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.com");

        //Find the element

        IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Name("q"));

        //Perform Operation
        element.SendKeys("Dynamics Lifecycle Services");

        driver.Close();
        }
        }
        }
```

this code opens chrome for split second and then throws exception as below

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WebDriver.dll
>
> Additional information: unknown error: unrecognized Blink revision:
>   49721773c8dd62828e471ca69e2c89767f98c690

A cmd promt opens with message :

> Only local connections are allowed.

Please help to resolve. thanks in advance